# Proving mapping is contraction

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that mapping $B:C[0,\tau]\to C[0,\tau]$.
$$(Bx)(t)=\left( \int_0^\tau \sin x(s)ds\right) t, \ t\in [0,\tau], \ \tau >0$$
is contraction mapping if $\tau^2<1$.

I want to show that for all $x,y\in C[0,\tau]$
$$\varrho(B(x),B(y))\leqslant \varrho(x,y)$$
I've got so far
\begin{align*}
\varrho((Bx)(t),(By)(t))&=\| (Bx)(t)-(By)(t)\| \\
&= \max_{0\leqslant t \leqslant \tau}\left|\left(\int_0^\tau \sin x(s)ds\right) t-\left(\int_0^\tau \sin y(s)ds\right) t\right| \\
&= \max_{0\leqslant t \leqslant \tau}t\left|\left(\int_0^\tau (\sin x(s)-\sin y(s))ds\right)\right| 
\end{align*}
Any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: Something is not right above: do you mean that $B$ is just a constant multiplied by $t$? It seems too easy to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sine has derivative bounded by $1$, the mean value theorem gives $|\sin u - \sin v| \le |u - v|$ for all $u, v \in \Bbb R$. Thus

$$\left|\int_0^\tau (\sin x(s) - \sin y(s))\, ds\right| \le  \int_0^\tau |\sin x(s) - \sin y(s)|\, ds \le \int_0^\tau |x(s) - y(s)|\, ds.$$

So the expression you have in the last step is dominated by $\tau \int_0^\tau |x(s) - y(s)|\, ds,$ which is dominated by $\tau^2 \rho(x,y)$. Thus $$\rho(B(x),B(y)) \le \tau^2 \rho(x,y).$$

Since $\tau^2 < 1$, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

The following inequality holds, for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$: $$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leq|x-y|.$$  This can be seen by noticing that $x\mapsto\sin(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with Lipschitz constant 1.  With this inequality at hand, showing your map is a contraction for $\tau^2<1$ is straightforward.  The max occurs at $t=\tau$, and we have $|\int_0^\tau g(s)ds|\leq\int_0^\tau |g(s)|ds$ for any $g$ integrable.  In total, from where you left off, we get $$d(Bx,By)\leq\tau\int_0^\tau |x(s)-y(s)|ds\leq\tau\int_0^\tau \max_{0\leq t\leq \tau}|x(s)-y(s)|ds=\tau\int_0^\tau d(x,y)ds,$$ where here, I've used $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ to denote the metric on $C[0,\tau]$.  I think you can finish the rest

Comment: And a +1 to @kobe for beating me to it :)